# What is a good tutorial for learning vmr-9?

Tags: directshow

I need to combine 3d models from direct3d on top of a web cam feed.  I hear vmr-9 is a good way to go, but I need tutorials.  Anyone know of any?

visual studio 2008 c++

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Windows SDK installed there are a handful of great samples.  You should find them in here once the SDK is installed:

\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Samples\multimedia\directshow\vmr9